# React axios unauthorized... WHY

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, token, logout

I have one simple quesions. Why i have error 401 (unauthorized). Token is correct.
This method run after clikc the button

```
const getFile = (filename) => {  //filename = "wy8NNSV9uAvL0NPYydw5iaZDkz5XQYeFo2A7VZo0.pdf"
axios.get(
    "http://localhost:8000/api/files/" + filename, {},
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        responseType: "blob",
      },
    }
  )
  .then((res) => {
    const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });};
```

[After click button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWvMm.png)

Comment: Can you log `localStorage.getItem("token") `

Comment: yes, this works, token is correct'

Comment: It is very important that you read the documentation instead of writting code you have no idea about, because you are not a magician that will suddently know how to use axios (unless you have experience), so please, always check the docs first: https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios `get` method only takes 2 argument.

Try to go from:

```js
axios.get(uri, data, config) 
// which is the syntax for post request
```

To:

```js
axios.get(uri, config)
```

In your code:

```js
const getFile = (filename) => {
axios.get(
    "uri" + filename, // here remove: {},
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        responseType: "blob",
      },
    }
  )
  .then((res) => {
    // ..
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```